# Can the Mods reset the Vote Count for good questions that received an unnecessary judgement?

Tags: support, voting, moderator-tools

I asked a [serious well formatted, no duplicated, and delicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717139/store-00-as-a-value) and maybe because some users had their leg bitten by their dog subsequently while looking at my answer they decided to downvote it.

This makes the site look unprofessional and opinion based.

Comment: Mods can't reset votes. But they delete the entire question - if that counts as "resetting" it.

Answer (score 4):

No, moderators have no ability to alter upvotes or downvotes on a post beyond their own votes. The only "special" thing they can do is lock a post, which locks the score.

Answer (score 4):

For such "how can I do this?" questions, users like to see attempts at solving the problem.  Not only does it show more effort at posting a quality question, but it also helps with giving a more specific question to answer.  Everything else can be spot-on, but indication of effort goes a long way.

Comment: I have an attempt....I have everything. Just why do people enjoy downvoting me for pleasure?

Comment: Would it be against the user if it had an influence from this question?

Comment: @BDillan: Only if someone used it as a reason to automatically downvote anything else you post.

Comment: It _is_ a problem if people downvote for reasons other than that they think the post is bad. There's just nothing that anyone else can do about it unless one user is targeting another with votes.